# C# Windows Forms - DataRepeater "Template-Based" Binding?

Tags: c#, winforms

I typically work with web forms but have a project that requires a windows form instead. I need to display data using a DataRepeater control however, I cannot bind directly to the data source as I need to "massage" the data before it is displayed. Using the web form version of the datarepeater this could be acheived using an ItemTemplate and passing the returned data item to a public method such as how I am passing it to the "GetModel" method in the example below. How can I accomplish something similiar in a windows form?

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lbAsModel" runat="server" Text='<%# GetModel(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("ALAN8"))) %>' CssClass="repGridText" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: If you want to do template based forms maybe take a look to wpf :)

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks assembly contains [a DataRepeater class for Winforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.datarepeater.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Just bind it to the massaged data...

Answer (score 0):

You can format bound data for display by handling the `Format` event on the `Binding` class. You'll just need to add your bindings manually (not using the designer).

Here's the [MSDN page with an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.format.aspx).